# React component life cycle invoke order

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to JavaScript. I recently starting learning ReactJS and read about components life cycle. What I gathered is that on initialization of a component the cycle looks like this:

```
GetDefaultProps -> GetInitialState -> ComponentWillMount -> Render -> ComponentDidMount
```

I also read that `getDefaultProps()` is called before any instances are created. If I have the following code:

```
class Sample extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        alert("In constructor");
    }
    getDefaultProps() {
        alert("In getDefaultProps");
    }
    render() {
        return <div></div>;
    }
}

React.render(<Sample/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

I assumed it would alert "In getDefaultProps", then "In constructor". But only "In constructor" is alerted. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to set default props now on es6 classes is with the [defaultProps](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#defaultprops) property

So you'd do something like this:

```
class Sample extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        alert("In constructor");
    }
    render() {
        return <div></div>;
    }
}

Sample.defaultProps = {
   sampleProp: 'sample',
};
```

Comment: Did you mean `sampleProp: 'sample'`? Also, does the `defaultProps` still come before `GetInitialState` in the cycle? Thanks.

Comment: `defaultProps` is no longer a function so it is set a single time during runtime. `GetInitialState` is also gone. That should now be set in the constructor using `this.state = { sampleState: 'sampleState' };`

Answer (score 1):

getDefaultProps() can be used to define any default props which can be accessed via this.props.

Suppose you have one child component Child and you are using that component in your parent component and passing a prop say testProp="this is test prop". Then in child component it can be used as this.props.testProps. But now the case is that in any way you need a value for this prop and suppose from parent component you are not sending this prop to child component. Then in that case getDefaultProps will come into picture, where you can set default value for that prop, if it is defined by parent then it will be used as the value from parent component else it will use default value.

So we can set default value for that prop in ES5 as:

```
getDefaultProps() {
  testProp="This is default value for test prop"
}
```

In ES6:

```
Sample.defaultProps = {
   testProp: 'This is default value for test prop',
};
```

Answer (score 0):

defaultprops can be defined within class using static keyword

```
static defaultProps = {
   test: "default value of test"
}
```